# Categorize data in Excel

Tags: excel, categorization

I have sheet "data" with values like these:

```
9000
9100
9105
9200
```

I have another sheet "categories":

```
Low    High   Value
9000   9100   1
9101   9200   2
9201   9300   3
```

I want to obtain sheet "data in categories":

```
1
1
2
2
```

How can I accomplish this using formulas?

Comment: Take a look at `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A1 in your new sheet ('Data in Categories') try to use this formula

```
=OFFSET(Categories!$C$1, SUMPRODUCT(--(Categories!$A$2:$A$4<=Data!A1)*(Categories!$B$2:$B$4>=Data!A1),ROW(Categories!$C$2:$C$4))-1, 0)
```

and copy it down

Result

```
--------
|  A1  |
--------
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    2 |
```

Source of the base idea of using `SUMPRODUCT` and detailed explanation is [Range Lookup in Excel](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/30/range-lookup-excel/)